# Storing graphs (weighted, directed, etc.)

Tags: data-structures, graph

I am studying for a upcoming CS interview and came across a study topic I was not too familiar with myself (outside of textbook and class knowledge, I am talking about code implementation: graphs).

How would one represent a graph? Just a linked list of nodes with a property of distance length to next node? A matrix? If its a matrix how can it be represented? Having some trouble finding some good examples on google.

Answer (score 0):

To prepare for interview, I think you would need to familiarize adjacency list & matrix.  Those are two most common graph representation. You can easily google their details.